# How can i install Java 8 to Google Compute Engine (Debian 10)

Tags: java, google-compute-engine, minecraft-forge, debian-buster

First of all, I would like to say that I'm not a programmer and I am not experienced in the field. I was trying to set up a Minecraft server in the Google Compute Engine and I set it up successfuly. However, when I tried to switch it to a different version I could not open it because the server was running java 11. I removed it and tried a bunch of things to install Java 8 but I couldn't do it. Is there a way that i can reliably use to install java 8 to my server?

Comment: Does `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre` work?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, It didn't work and I would like to give more information but when I was looking at true websites (not sure if it's allowed to post here). 
 I used these and for some reason all the commands I enter just echoes back to me. Trying to fix this right now. 
 
` echo deb http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main | sudo tee 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "false";' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf
sudo apt update
sudo apt -t jessie-backports install openjdk-8-jre `

Comment: Also sorry for ridiculous text but i couldn't figure out how to do code block.

Comment: You can always download the archive and extract it by yourself (e.g. from <https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u292-b10/OpenJDK8U-jre_x64_linux_hotspot_8u292b10.tar.gz>)

Comment: Do I transfer the file through a scp to server?

Comment: `scp` is one possibility. You could also directly download it from the server using tools like `curl` or `wget`.

Answer (score 0):

As you just pointed out, Debian 10's default and only officially supported java runtime is `openjdk-11-jre`.

Oracle provides their guide to download java on their website (https://java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.html#download), which you can download, extract, and run.

I also found a `nvidia-openjdk-8-jre` package in the non-free repository of debian buster / bullseye. It exists for compatibility reasons and it's [not recommendeded](https://lists.debian.org/debian-security/2020/04/msg00021.html), but it might work.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for both alternatives. If all else fails I might try the second route.